# How to implement RMI with Spring 4?

Tags: java, spring, rmi

**Update**

Sorry for not being clear in my question,  I am developing a Spring project with the next dependencies

- Spring Boot
- Spring Data
- Mysql
- wsdl

In the project I exposed soap Web services with Spring Data for persistence, I have to use RMI for support of application desktop.

I tried the following :

- Integrate in the same project Spring and RMI (using RMI Register ) successfully but when I tried use Spring annotations obviously not working.
- I'm searching when I found that Spring have support for RMI using XML configuration but  I need the configuration in annotations.

My question How to would implement RMI in my project?

I'm using latest version in all dependencies

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to use the same RMI mechanism as in Spring 3? I don't see that, it has nothing to do with using java or xml for configuration.

Comment: @M.Deinum Because I have to use Spring 4 by client,  also I consider  the time in create and add the necessary for the project when the use annotations is easy

Comment: Still what has that to do with the fact that you can or cannot use the RMI support in spring... That has nothing to do with the Spring version or the fact that you use or not use XML.

Comment: the beans you want to use which implement the RMI are in the spring-context. If you check now at maven , spring context is at 4+version http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context.

Comment: Also hope that you have red the spring's doc : http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#remoting-rmi-server

Comment: Please clarify what you want (using xml config or whatever) and what have you tried using that in the form of java, currently there isn't really a clear question.